# VM1374:32 Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON(…)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, reactjs

I am new to JS. I am trying to print the values in my console.log. I am getting the below error:

```
VM1374:32 Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON(…)
```

My code is below:

```
console.log("this.props.children[this.state.selected]---->" + JSON.stringify(this.props.children[this.state.selected]));
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a pretty common problem. `Converting circular structure to JSON(...)` is thrown because you're trying to print out an object that eventually references itself through one of its properties.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ut8L0do/) of one of the simplest ways you can get this issue:

```
var a = {
  b: null
};

// Prints fine
console.log(JSON.stringify(a, null, 3));

a.b = a;

// Throws an error, as a.b *is* a
console.log(JSON.stringify(a, null, 3));
```

When you call `JSON.stringify`, the browser will traverse your object like a big tree, going down each property like a branch and converting what it can into a string.
In the example above, the property `b` at first is null, which results in a successful "stringification". When we set `a.b` to `a` itself, we now get this sort of tree:

```
a
|-b: a
     |-b: a
          |-b: a
               ...
```

The structure is *circular* in this way because the object references itself. There's no way to write that as JSON because it would go on forever, so an error is thrown.

For your specific problem, this is happening in React because the React objects reference their parents, which reference their children, which reference their parents, which reference their children... it goes on forever.

So you can't use `JSON.stringify` on `this` or `this.props` in your example for this reason (`this.props` has the property `children` that is partly responsible for the issue).

You will notice that you *can* stringify `this.state`, as that's a normal object that doesn't reference any other React objects:

```
> JSON.stringify(this.state);
"{"selected":0}"
```

Edit: What may be best for you is to just `console.log` without `JSON.stringify`:

```
console.log("this.props.children[this.state.selected]---->", this.props.children[this.state.selected]);
```

You can add multiple arguments to `console.log` and separate them with commas, then the browser console itself should print it in a viewable format.

Comment: but how to print this value and see JSON.stringify(this.props)

Comment: @texirv - If you're just printing it out to see for yourself, you don't need to `JSON.stringify` it. Just add it to your `console.log`, and the browser console will make it viewable. See my edited answer.

Comment: That's a different question, which I'll take a look at. If I've answered this question properly, please mark it as your accepted answer.

Comment: thanks for your help...I tried debugging other question...but I am not able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

// Include this function into your code and call to
// resolve this issue

```
stringify(obj) {
    let cache = [];
    let str = JSON.stringify(obj, function(key, value) {
      if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
        if (cache.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
          // Circular reference found, discard key
          return;
        }
        // Store value in our collection
        cache.push(value);
      }
      return value;
    });
    cache = null; // reset the cache
    return str;
  }
```