# Vue variable dumping all data at top of page for testing

Tags: json, debugging, vuejs2, dump

Currently trying

```
{{$data}}
```

The error is

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

I can do

```
   {{ $store.state }}
```

and am sure I used to be able to do in Vue V1

```
  {{ $data | json }}
```

How do I get all the data to dump in the browser?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40499339/vm137432-uncaught-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Vue Devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) for debugging Vue.js applications.

By the way, `{{$data}}` works fine (without circular structure).