# Disqus comments throws error in a Gatsby site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, disqus, gatsby-plugin

I am using a gatsby plugin gatsby-plugin-disqus(latest version) to add comments in my gatsby site. It worked previously but now it throws error and comments do not load. Seems like there's circular reference but I don't know what is causing it.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'HTMLDivElement'
|     property '__reactInternalInstance$ijgm46blrc' -> object with constructor 'FiberNode'
--- property 'stateNode' closes the circle
at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
at b.Channel.h.sendMessage (embed.js:44)
at e.<anonymous> (embed.js:45)
at e.<anonymous> (embed.js:44)
at e.<anonymous> (embed.js:44)
at m (embed.js:44)
at e.trigger (embed.js:44)
at e.<anonymous> (embed.js:44)
at m (embed.js:44)
at b.Channel.trigger (embed.js:44)
at embed.js:44
```

My disqus config looks like:

```
const disqusConfig = {
  identifier: "/my-post-title-slug/"
  title: "my post title"
  url: "https://somesite.com/blog/my-post-title-slug/"
}
```

And i render it like this:

```
import { Disqus } from 'gatsby-plugin-disqus';
// ....
<Disqus config={disqusConfig} />
```

I am not sure what is causing this problem. I tried to use previous versions of the plugin but i get the same result.

Please let me know what i am missing here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That is... odd. You usually see this type of issue when attempting to stringify an object containing circuluar references. Ex:

[VM1374:32 Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON(…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40499339/vm137432-uncaught-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json)

But the object you're passing in is simple, containing only string values. I'm wondering if this isn't being caused by Disqus at all, but instead is something else in the mix.

To verify it shouldn't be an issue, I mimicked the exact same set up with a local Gatsby site of my own (v4), using the v1.2.4 of the Disqus package. I see no errors.

That said... my proposed steps:

1. Confirm that it's not being caused by a different package.
2. Try padding the config object directly into the component. I don't know why it'd yield a different result, but it's worth a shot:

```
<Disqus
  config={{
    identifier: "/my-post-title-slug/",
    title: "my post title",
    url: "https://somesite.com/blog/my-post-title-slug/"
  }}
/>
```

If it's too much of a hassle, think about trying a Disqus alternative. I built one of my own after hitting a tons of frustrations with Disqus, including performance and lack of SEO-friendliness. You're welcome to try it out:

https://jamcomments.com

Comment: I actually ended up using Graph Comment, due to this and performance reasons.